# Debugar Proc no banco de dados sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Uso o Sql Server 2014. Estou com problemas em Stored procedure, pois ao executar com determinados filtros, me dispara esse erro:

> Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento
>   SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_INATIVOS, Linha 485 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,> >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Pelo erro, dá para ver que uma subquery está retornando mais de uma registro e isso pode ser um Where mal formado e etc...

Como eu faço para quando eu executar essa proc, eu consigo parar exatamente na linha do erro. Aí diz linha 485, mas ao ir até a linha 485, parece que está tudo ok e pode ser mais em cima e veio estourar nessa linha um erro que aconteceu antes, sei lá, não sei se isso é possível.

Fiz conforme o colega Ismael orientou e me retornou isso:

> Err Nº: 512 | Severidade: 16 | Estado: 1 | Procedure:
>   SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_INATIVOS | Linha: 389 | Erro: Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   Mensagem 50000, Nível 1, Estado 16

Só que a linha 389 não tem nada nela, está em branco e ela está em cima do `BEGIN TRY`.

Meu bloco de código da Proc está assim:

```
........
BEGIN TRY
                            IF @ID_XFC_GRP <> '' OR @ID_XFC_Inicial <> 0
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.RAM_ATV,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_NASC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_MAE_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.IR_SEX_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SUS_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_RG_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_CPF_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_CID_END, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.SG_UF_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_FUN_ULT, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_SET_ULT,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_DMS_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_SET_UNI,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_SET_UNI, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_FUN,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_FNL_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DS_MAT_CTO,
                                            isNull( OIT1980LEITURA.DT_RX, EXAME_RAIOX.DT_EXM_REA ) DT_RX,
                                            OIT1980LEITURA.RX_NUM,
                                            EXAME_RAIOX.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_RAIOX,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as CVF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_LMT,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_MED,
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as VEF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_MED, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_POR, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_POR as varchar(7)),'.', ',') as FEF_POR,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_LMT,
                                            EXAME.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_ESPIROMETRIA,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_DTLH_CLSS,
                                            CIDADE_UNIDADE.NM_CID_END AS CIDADE 
                                            , EXAME.DT_EXM_REA DT_EXA_EXP
                                            , NM_EMP,
                                            (   Select NO_TEL_UNI_EMP From t_cmo_unidade
                                                Where ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP ) Telefone,
                                            (   Select DS_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Endereco,
                                            (   Select NM_BRR_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Bairro,
                                            (   Select CD_CEP From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) CEP,
                                            (   Select NM_CID_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Cidade,
                                            (   Select SG_UF_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) UF

                                       FROM #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO 
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO    
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_OIT1980_LEITURA OIT1980LEITURA
                                            ON OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT_LET = 1
                                            AND OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT = (SELECT ID_OIT FROM T_CMO_OIT1980 
                                                                                WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                            AND   ID_EXM = 3936     
                                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação  
                                                                                                    )
                                                                    )           
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME_RAIOX
                                                                                     ON  EXAME_RAIOX.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER     
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC 
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                          WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                          AND   ID_EXM = 3936       
                                                                                                                                          AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação    
                                                                                                                    )
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA ESPIROMETRIA
                                                             ON  ESPIROMETRIA.ID_EXP = (SELECT ID_EXP FROM T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA
                                                                                                      WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                                    WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                                    AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                                                                    AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                                                            )
                                                                                        )       
                                            --PARA PEGAR A OBS DA ESPIROMETRIA
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME
                                            ON  EXAME.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER
                                            AND EXAME.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC        
                                            AND EXAME.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                            AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                    )                                       
                                            left outer join T_CMO_ENDERECO AS CIDADE_UNIDADE
                                                ON  CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_emp = @ID_EMP 
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_uni_emp = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.IR_TIP_END = 'U'

                                     WHERE  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP = @ID_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC in(SELECT ID_XFC FROM #FUNCIONARIOS_INATIVOS)

                                        --AND YEAR(EXAME.DT_EXM_REA) BETWEEN @DT_DE_LAUDO AND @DT_ATE_LAUDO

                                        ORDER BY #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC

                                END
                            ELSE 
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.RAM_ATV,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_NASC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_MAE_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.IR_SEX_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SUS_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_RG_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_CPF_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_CID_END, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.SG_UF_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_FUN_ULT, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_SET_ULT,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_DMS_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_SET_UNI,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_SET_UNI, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_FUN,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_FNL_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DS_MAT_CTO,
                                            OIT1980LEITURA.DT_RX,
                                            OIT1980LEITURA.RX_NUM,
                                            EXAME_RAIOX.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_RAIOX,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as CVF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_LMT,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_MED,
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as VEF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_MED, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_POR, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_POR as varchar(7)),'.', ',') as FEF_POR,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_LMT,
                                            EXAME.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_ESPIROMETRIA,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_DTLH_CLSS,
                                            CIDADE_UNIDADE.NM_CID_END AS CIDADE 
                                            , EXAME.DT_EXM_REA DT_EXA_EXP
                                            , NM_EMP,
                                            (   Select NO_TEL_UNI_EMP From t_cmo_unidade
                                                Where ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP ) Telefone,
                                            (   Select DS_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Endereco,
                                            (   Select NM_BRR_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Bairro,
                                            (   Select CD_CEP From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) CEP,
                                            (   Select NM_CID_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Cidade,
                                            (   Select SG_UF_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) UF

                                       FROM #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO 
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO    
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_OIT1980_LEITURA OIT1980LEITURA
                                            ON OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT_LET = 1
                                            AND OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT = (SELECT ID_OIT FROM T_CMO_OIT1980 
                                                                                WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                            AND   ID_EXM = 3936     
                                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação  
                                                                                                    )
                                                                    )           
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME_RAIOX
                                                                                     ON  EXAME_RAIOX.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER     
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC 
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                          WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                          AND   ID_EXM = 3936       
                                                                                                                                          AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação    
                                                                                                                    )
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA ESPIROMETRIA
                                                             ON  ESPIROMETRIA.ID_EXP = (SELECT ID_EXP FROM T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA
                                                                                                      WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                                    WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                                    AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                                                                    AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                                                            )
                                                                                        )       
                                            --PARA PEGAR A OBS DA ESPIROMETRIA
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME
                                            ON  EXAME.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER
                                            AND EXAME.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC        
                                            AND EXAME.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                            AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                    )                                       
                                             left outer join T_CMO_ENDERECO AS CIDADE_UNIDADE
                                                ON  CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_emp = @ID_EMP 
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_uni_emp = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.IR_TIP_END = 'U'

                                     WHERE  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP = @ID_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC  IN (SELECT ID_XFC FROM #FUNCIONARIOS_INATIVOS)
                                        --AND EXISTS(SELECT ID_XFC FROM #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO 
                                                                --WHERE #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC < @DT_ADM
                                                            --AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC       
                                                                    --)

                                        --AND YEAR(EXAME.DT_EXM_REA) BETWEEN @DT_DE_LAUDO AND @DT_ATE_LAUDO

                                        ORDER BY #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC
                                END
                            END TRY
                            BEGIN CATCH

                                DECLARE @_ERROR_PROCEDURE VARCHAR(MAX)
                                SET @_ERROR_PROCEDURE = 'Err Nº: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Severidade: '+ CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Estado: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Procedure: '+ ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') +
                                     ' | Linha: '+ CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Erro: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE()

                                RAISERROR(@_ERROR_PROCEDURE,1,16)

                            END CATCH
........
```

Setei uma variável do tipo `int` assim:

```
declare 
@Contador int = 0

IF @ID_XFC_GRP <> '' OR @ID_XFC_Inicial <> 0
                                BEGIN
                                set @Contador = 8
                                    SELECT  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.RAM_ATV,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_LAU_PER,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DT_NASC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_MAE_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.IR_SEX_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SUS_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_RG_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_CPF_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_CID_END, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.SG_UF_END,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_FUN_ULT, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NM_SET_ULT,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_DMS_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_UNI_EMP,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_SET_UNI,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_SET_UNI, 
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.NM_FUN,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_FNL_PER_FUN_XFC,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DS_MAT_CTO,
                                            isNull( OIT1980LEITURA.DT_RX, EXAME_RAIOX.DT_EXM_REA ) DT_RX,
                                            OIT1980LEITURA.RX_NUM,
                                            EXAME_RAIOX.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_RAIOX,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as CVF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.CVF_LMT,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_MED,
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_POR as varchar(7)), '.', ',') as VEF_POR,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_PRE, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_MED, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_POR, 
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.VEF_CVF_LMT,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_PRE,  
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_MED, 
                                            Replace(Cast(ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_POR as varchar(7)),'.', ',') as FEF_POR,
                                            ESPIROMETRIA.FEF_LMT,
                                            EXAME.DS_OBS_EXM_REA AS DS_ESPIROMETRIA,
                                            #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.DS_DTLH_CLSS,
                                            CIDADE_UNIDADE.NM_CID_END AS CIDADE 
                                            , EXAME.DT_EXM_REA DT_EXA_EXP
                                            , NM_EMP,
                                            (   Select NO_TEL_UNI_EMP From t_cmo_unidade
                                                Where ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP ) Telefone,
                                            (   Select DS_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Endereco,
                                            (   Select NM_BRR_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Bairro,
                                            (   Select CD_CEP From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) CEP,
                                            (   Select NM_CID_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) Cidade,
                                            (   Select SG_UF_END From t_cmo_endereco 
                                                Where IR_TIP_END = 'U' and ID_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP and ID_UNI_EMP = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP    ) UF

                                       FROM #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO 
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO    
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO
                                            ON #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.ID_XFC

                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_OIT1980_LEITURA OIT1980LEITURA
                                            ON OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT_LET = 1
                                            AND OIT1980LEITURA.ID_OIT = (SELECT ID_OIT FROM T_CMO_OIT1980 
                                                                                WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                            AND   ID_EXM = 3936     
                                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação  
                                                                                                    )
                                                                    )           
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME_RAIOX
                                                                                     ON  EXAME_RAIOX.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER     
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC 
                                                                                     AND EXAME_RAIOX.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                          WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                          AND   ID_EXM = 3936       
                                                                                                                                          AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0)--NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação    
                                                                                                                    )
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA ESPIROMETRIA
                                                             ON  ESPIROMETRIA.ID_EXP = (SELECT ID_EXP FROM T_CMO_ESPIROMETRIA
                                                                                                      WHERE ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                                                                    WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                                                                    AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                                                                    AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                                                            )
                                                                                        )       
                                            --PARA PEGAR A OBS DA ESPIROMETRIA
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO AS EXAME
                                            ON  EXAME.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER
                                            AND EXAME.ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC        
                                            AND EXAME.ID_EXM_REA = (SELECT MAX(ID_EXM_REA) FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO
                                                                                                            WHERE ID_XFC = #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC
                                                                                                            AND   (ID_EXM = 1514 OR ID_EXM = 3136)
                                                                                                            AND   NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER = ISNULL(#T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, 0) --NO_SEQ_AVA_LAU_PER, para filtro por avaliação
                                                                                    )                                       
                                            left outer join T_CMO_ENDERECO AS CIDADE_UNIDADE
                                                ON  CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_emp = @ID_EMP 
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.id_uni_emp = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                                and CIDADE_UNIDADE.IR_TIP_END = 'U'

                                     WHERE  #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_EMP = @ID_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_UNI_EMP = @ID_UNI_EMP
                                        AND #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC in(SELECT ID_XFC FROM #FUNCIONARIOS_INATIVOS)

                                        --AND YEAR(EXAME.DT_EXM_REA) BETWEEN @DT_DE_LAUDO AND @DT_ATE_LAUDO

                                        ORDER BY #T_SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_FUNCIONARIO.ID_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_ADMISSAO.DT_ADM_PER_CPC_XFC,
                                                 #T_SP_CMO_SEL_REL_FICHA_FUNCAO.DT_INI_PER_FUN_XFC

                                END
                            ELSE 
                                BEGIN
                                set @Contador = 9
```

No catch fiz isso:

```
BEGIN CATCH

                                DECLARE @_ERROR_PROCEDURE VARCHAR(MAX)
                                SET @_ERROR_PROCEDURE = 'Err Nº: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Severidade: '+ CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Estado: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Procedure: '+ ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') +
                                     ' | Linha: '+ CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                                     ' | Erro: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE() +
                                     ' | Contador: ' + CAST(@Contador AS VARCHAR(10))

                                RAISERROR(@_ERROR_PROCEDURE,1,16)

                            END CATCH
```

O valor impresso para Contador foi o 8, então acho que o problema está no select abaixo dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de realizar o *debug* que normalmente utilizo em minhas *Store Procedures* é com o uso do [`TRY / CATCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175976.aspx). Veja um exemplo:

Observe que o SQL inicia a contagem conforme a *query* que você criou.
Sempre vai incluir todas as linhas em branco do início ou após o `GO`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE TESTE_PRO   --outra query
GO                         --separador  
                           --LINHA 1 -> mesmo em branco já faz parte da procedure 
                           --LINHA 2
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTE_PRO --LINHA 3
AS
BEGIN TRY
                           --LINHA 6
                           --LINHA 7
    DECLARE @TE1 INT;
    DECLARE @TE2 INT;

    SET @TE1 = 0

    SET @TE2 = 1/0;        --LINHA 13
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @_ERROR_PROCEDURE VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @_ERROR_PROCEDURE = 'Err Nº: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' | Severidade: '+ CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' | Estado: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' | Procedure: '+ ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') +
                            ' | Linha: '+ CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' | Erro: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE()

    RAISERROR(@_ERROR_PROCEDURE,1,16)
END CATCH

GO
EXEC TESTE_PRO
```

O **[`RAISERROR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178592.aspx)** vai retornar os dados que escolhi, inclusive o número da linha que ocorreu a exceção pelo comando **[`ERROR_LINE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178600.aspx)**.

> Err Nº: 8134 | Severidade: 16 | Estado: 1 | Procedure: TESTE_PRO | Linha: 13 | Erro: Erro de divisão por zero.
>   Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16

*Obs: Eu coloquei todos esses dados no catch porque depois eu o salvo em um log.*

### Atualização da resposta

Execute um `sp_helptext teste_pro`  e veja exatamente como o SQL fará a enumeração das linhas.

Comment: Tem como colocar parte da sua proc? Recrie a procedure em uma nova query. Somente a procedure, de forma que a primeira linha na IDE seja o `create proc`.

Comment: Coloquei o código referente ao retorno da Proc na edição do post.

Comment: Você tem que postar o código desde o início, pq de lá que iremos contar as linhas.

Comment: Fiz um debug tipo javascript com `Alert()`. Criei uma variável do tipo int e fui setando a variável em cada bloco. A última Impressão que eu peguei no catch, foi 8, isso quer dizer que o erro aconteceu logo a seguir, senão teria imprimido 9 e não 8.

Comment: @pnet Atualizei a resposta com um comando que vai te ajudar.

Comment: @pnet Todos os *subselects* internos que são utilizados como coluna ou nos `where` onde a sintaxe é **campo = subconsulta** (desde que não use qualquer função de agregação como o sum, max etc) poderiam ser garantidos com um `TOP 1`.

Comment: Entendi. O insert que dei no banco, é que quebrou tudo, mas vou considerar, só que não posso alterar muito essa proc. Não fui quem fiz e tá osso entender o negócio aqui.